# PyMODIS: Setup and Running

Tags: python, modis, pymodis

I have installed pyMODIS along with Numpy and the necassary GDAL bindings.

How do I go about running the scripts such as modis_convert.py and modis_download_from_list.py.

Are these ran from the command prompt?

I have also attempted to run them from the Python IDLE but have got Syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`modis_convert.py` and  `modis_download_from_list.py.` are Python scripts therefore in the  command prompt, type

```
python modis_convert.py
```

With the adequate parameters.

If you want to use PyModis from the command prompt or IDLE, you need to import the module

```
python
.....
from pymodis import downmodis
```

....

The examples are in the Jupyter/Ipython notebook (/.../pyModis-2.0.2/docs/source/examples/pyModis.ipynb